# Ошибка при переборе словаря, key error

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

Столкнулся с проблемой:
Есть словарь, содержащий в себе данные про операции в количестве 100 штук
Написал программу которая перебирает словарь, и выдает нужную операцию по ID либо по ее порядковому номеру.

Суть проблемы:
Выдает только ДО 74 операции включительно, дальше выдает

```
  if int(user_input) == i['id']:
KeyError: 'id'
```

Структура словаря при этом не меняется.

```py
if user_input.isnumeric():
    if int(user_input) not in range(1, self.counts) and int(user_input) not in self.ids:
        print(error.wrong_id())
        return error.wrong_id()
    else:
        if len(user_input) > 3: # Это вывод по ID
            for i in self.operations_dict:
                if int(user_input) == i['id']:
                    return self.information(i)

        if len(user_input) < 4: # Это вывод по порядковому номеру
            for i in self.operations_dict:
                if self.ids[int(user_input)-1] == i['id']:
                    return self.information(i)
```

Нерабочий пример из словаря:

```py
{
  "id": 667307132,
  "state": "EXECUTED",
  "date": "2019-07-13T18:51:29.313309",
  "operationAmount": {
    "amount": "97853.86",
    "currency": {
      "name": "руб.",
      "code": "RUB"
    }
  },
  "description": "Перевод с карты на счет",
  "from": "Maestro 1308795367077170",
  "to": "Счет 96527012349577388612"
}
```

Рабочий пример из словаря:

```py
{
  "id": 441945886,
  "state": "EXECUTED",
  "date": "2019-08-26T10:50:58.294041",
  "operationAmount": {
    "amount": "31957.58",
    "currency": {
      "name": "руб.",
      "code": "RUB"
    }
  },
  "description": "Перевод организации",
  "from": "Maestro 1596837868705199",
  "to": "Счет 64686473678894779589"
}
```

Comment: Сам словарь то покажите. Вернее, судя по всему, `self.operations_dict` - это список словарей, потому что если бы это был словарь, то вы бы перебирали через `for` ключи этого словаря и конструкция `i['id']` вообще не имела бы смысла. У вас видимо там список словарей, вот и приложите его к вопросу. Скорее всего в каком-то из словарей в этом списке действительно нет ключа `id`, а вот что с этим делать - зависит от того, что у вас там на самом деле и что вы вообще хотите. А может вы где-то в процессе работы кода как-то портите этот словарь, всё может быть. Тогда нужен будет весь код.

Comment: А вам как удобнее будет чтобы я его приложил? Просто там более 1400 строк в словаре, но вы правы, это словарь в словаре

Comment: Приложил 2 варианта из словаря, рабочий и нет

Comment: у вас эти данные из файла читаются? такое ощущение, что там что-то сбилось, например пустой словарь записан или что-то такое.  посмотрите внимательно перед первым сбойным местом. сделайте try except и распечатайте переменную i - посмотрите, что там

Comment: И всё-равно я не понимаю. Если делать перебор вот так `for i in self.operations_dict`, то в случае если в `self.operations_dict` находится словарь, в `i` будут перебираться **ключи** словаря. Ключи словаря в вашем случае - просто строки. Тогда `i['key']` всегда будет давать ошибку, потому что `i` - это **не словарь**. Работать это всё будет только в случае, если в `self.operations_dict` лежит **список** словарей, а не **словарь словарей**.

Comment: Не уверен что на сайте можно оставлять ссылки, но вот - https://jsonkeeper.com/b/Y7AL

Comment: Ну да, у вас там именно как я и думал **список словарей**. И один из словарей у вас просто пустой. Проверить это и обойти можно либо как написано в ответе, либо `if i and int(user_input) == i['id']:` либо `if 'id' in i and int(user_input) == i['id']:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал использовать **.get(serchkey, default_value_for_None_key)**, где:

- serchkey - искомый ключ
- default_value_for_None_key - дефолтное значение для отсутствующего ключа

Например так:

```
d = {'k1': 'val1',
     'k2': 'val2'}

for search_key_dict in ['k2','k3']:
    if (key_dict:= d.get(search_key_dict, None)):
        print(f'бла бла.. есть ключ {search_key_dict} его значение: {key_dict}')
    else:
        print(f'эх, ключа  {search_key_dict} нет...')
        continue
```

Выдаст такое:

```
бла бла.. есть ключ k2 его значение: val2
эх, ключа  k3 нет...
```

---

Соответственно, у Вас вышло бы что-то такое:

```
if len(user_input) > 3:
    for i in self.operations_dict:
        if (id_key := i.get('id')) and id_key == int(user_input):
            return self.information(i)
```

Comment: Не знаю кто вам минусанул, но ваше решение помогло :) Спасибо!